# Custom e-mail translation in Drupal 8

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I need to send some e-mails depending on some actions. These e-mails should be translated depending on the target user's preferred language. I've seen that the mail function has a language parameter, but for me, it's not really do anything.

```
  $renderArray = [
    '#theme' => 'email_notification_content_update',
    '#name' => $node->getOwner()->getDisplayName(),
    '#content_title' => $node->getTitle(),
    '#content_url' => $node->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])
      ->toString(),
    '#unfollow_url' => Url::fromRoute('flag.field_entry.delete', [
      'flag' => 'flag_name',
      'entity_id' => $node->id(),
    ])->setAbsolute()->toString(),
  ];

  $this->mailManager->mail(
    'my_module',
    'email_notification_content_update',
    $follower->getEmail(),
    $follower->language()->getId(),
    [
      'body' => $this->renderer->renderRoot($renderArray),
      'subject' => $this->t('An update of the content @title has been updated.', ['@title' => $node->getTitle()]),
    ]
  );
```

Currently, the e-mail text is in twig file (with links) and the parameters are passed to it at render. Now I can put the whole twig file in `{% trans %}` tags, but is there a better way? Like using the mail function's language parameter? Is there a better way to make a custom e-mail sending and have translations to them?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that the rendering (and therefore the translation) happens at $this->renderer->renderRoot(). I'd create a mail key handler, and build the body inside that handler. I'm not sure, but it may be that drupal switches to the given language at the ->mail function before processing the custom hook.

```
  $this->mailManager->mail(
    'mymodule',
    'content_update',
    $follower->getEmail(),
    $follower->language()->getId(),
    [
      'node' => $node,
    ]
  );
```

/mymodule.module

```
<?php

use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Implements hook_mail().
 */
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
  $renderer = Drupal::service('renderer');

  if ($key === 'content_update') {
    $node = $params['node'];
    $renderArray = [
      '#theme' => 'email_notification_content_update',
      '#name' => $node->getOwner()->getDisplayName(),
      '#content_title' => $node->getTitle(),
      '#content_url' => $node->toUrl('canonical', ['absolute' => TRUE])
        ->toString(),
      '#unfollow_url' => Url::fromRoute('flag.field_entry.delete', [
        'flag' => 'flag_name',
        'entity_id' => $node->id(),
      ])->setAbsolute()->toString(),
    ];
    $message['body'] = $renderer->renderRoot($renderArray);
    $message['subject'] = t("Content :title has been updated", [':title' => $node->label()]),
  }
}
```

Comment: How to respond to the mail key: https://code-examples.net/en/docs/drupal~8/core-core.api.php/function/hook_mail/8.1.x

Comment: Well, I sill don't see actually why the language parameter exists, I tried to debug but I didn't find the usage and I totally don't see currently why should I define the body and subject in the `hook_mail` when it will won't change anything... And I also guessing body can't be a renderable array...

Comment: I updated the answer, since hook_mail has no sign of language parameters I asume that drupal has a magic way to change to the given language before executing hook_mail. You can alter the subject and body parameter inside hook_mail.